# Design Mode not working in Flex Builder 3

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

When i try to open my mxml script in design mode i'm always getting following message "This Component is base on VBox, which is not a visual component. Switch to source mode to edit it"

Anything wrong with my installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to Flex Builder 3.0.1 to use design mode with Flex 3.1 SDK. You can download the latest Flex Builder update at http://www.adobe.com/support/flex/downloads_updaters.html.

Please check this link
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/406/kb406059.html